# Which MoCap Animation Sits

Tags: animation, unity

I have an UMA that I want to be in a sitting position basically forever. I assume I need an animation that will put him in an idle sitting position.

I found the MoCap Huge Animation library for free in the Assets Store, but it is so big that I don't know which animation is sitting.

Does anyone know of an idle sitting animation that I could use? Or specifically which number (ie 02_01) of the MoCap Huge Library which has one?

Answer (score -1):

See the 13_01 - 13_42. Many look weird though.